# Acid catalyzed bromine substitution in an alcoholic ester. What is the major product and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: The Question]

This was in a paper I gave. I want to know the mechanism by which both of these products will be formed and why is the 1st one the major product.
My thinking is that the -OH group will be converted into a good leaving group by protonating it and then a 2-degree Carbocation will be formed which should give Product 2. But the answer given is product 1 (which will go through a 1-degree carbocation as an intermediate). 
The 1st product:

### [image: The 1st Product]

The 2nd product:

[image: The 2nd product]

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the stability of the allylic cation and the size of the bromine anion.

Comment: I think if the reaction is under kinetic control (low temperature) then it proceeds with the most stable intermediate, so product $2$. But if the reaction is under thermodynamic control (high temperature), then the more stable product, the more substituted alkene $1$ will be formed. They have not mentioned the temperature, so not sure which one to choose.

Comment: In such papers if there isn't a symbol of 'Delta" i.e. heat then it isn't high temperature. So, according to your theory product 2 must form as a major pdt, which is what I had marked in the exam, but its wrong according to the paper setters. Any other logic? @TRC

Comment: Are you sure they mention heat every time? For instance, hydrolysis of the cyanide group to carboxylic acid makes heating essential - but I rarely see anything except $\ce{H3O^+}$ mentioned for the hydrolysis - in the same exam.

Comment: Besides, there is a famous question of addition of $\ce{HBr}$ to $1,3-$butadiene that most students come across while preparing for JEE. There the "high temperature" for thermodynamic control is $40^oC$. Do you think that temperature will be mentioned separately as heat?

Comment: I'm not saying it's your fault. I would probably have made the same mistake. Most of these data are experimental, and unless you have seen and memorized the results of the same reaction on that very same compound, it's nearly impossible to predict the product directly. It's all the fault of the paper setters.

Comment: How'd you know that this question was asked in JEE? @TRC bcoz I didn't mention that.

Comment: @GuyEternal most highschool questions here are from JEE students. But you can clarify if your exam mentions temperature for every reaction.

Comment: @GuyEternal The font of the question in your image is an exact match of the kind of font that NTA uses when it releases the response sheet, which it had done just the day before yesterday ;) So I guessed it was from there. Plus this is the kind of nonsensical question only NTA will ask in JEE Mains. Please correct me if I'm wrong - is it from some other exam?

Comment: Yeah Yeah it is from Mains @TRC

Answer (score -2):

This reaction called [Electrophilic addition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/electrophilic-addition) to α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds.

> Electrophilic addition to α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds is
> analogous to electrophilic addition to isolated double bonds, except
> that the electrophile adds to the carbonyl oxygen, the most basic atom
> in the molecule. After that, the nucleophile adds to the β carbon, and
> the resulting intermediate enol tautomerizes to the more stable
> carbonyl compound.

The 1st & 2nd products are incorrect.

> What is the major product and why?

---

The major product reaction mechanism should be as follows
[image]

and the reaction mechanism for the minor product is

[image]

---

Why?

As the carbonyl is protonated then the intermediate cation is a stronger electrophile and will react with the bromide ion.

Comment: I believe this *might* be incorrect - as far as I know the protonation occurs fastest at that position where the most stable carbocation is first formed. Your carbocation forming during Michael addition is primary and unstable. The carbocation formed by protonating and removing the alcohol group is secondary and allyl - more stable.

Comment: I would expect acid-base reaction leading to removal of water a much faster reaction. We do have concentrated HBr here, since acid-base is way faster than electrophlilic addition,  there may be a discrepancy with the source you have mentioned because it does not take into account the presence of alcohols.

Comment: @ThermEster Thankyou for your answer but I think that the effect of alcoholic grp isn't taken into account in your answer (as pointed out by @napstablook). I understood the answer after discussing in the comments.